How to represent a list of items which can be edited or deleted without taking a lot of space on the page?
I have a long list of items which user can edit or delete. Previously, I had all of them as a list on a page with edit and delete button. But now it is too big and I want to change the representation somehow.

I was thinking about dropdown with all these items (user can select only 1 of items from the list). But how to apply UX best practices to avoid getting something too complex and hard to use? (like a dropdown with text, edit and delete buttons, where field is changing where you click on edit, etc)

How would you solve this issue?

Any mockup to see the issue?

If the list is too long to display on a page, you'll have the same issue when you put the list into a dropdown. Actually, you'll probably have even less space.
The best solution to the problem is to work out how to break up the list into smaller sections or categories, so that you can reduce the amount of items in the list while still making it easy for the user to understand where to find things.
In UX design, the goal is to try and solve the root cause of the problem rather than to shift it somewhere else. Over time this leads to more design complexity and debt, which often doesn't get paid back and can get you in all sorts of strife.

I see what you mean, thanks
I want to add some clarification - the list is not too long, it is a list of saved filters by user. I don't think there will be more than 10 items there. But still I have this section in settings view (which takes only 1/4 of a screen) and I don't want to clutter it too much, so I thought about dropdown.
Which UI elements would you use to solve something like this?

A list with edit and delete buttons sounds more like a table. Ten items is a nice size to fit into a table, and you can even include other common operations like 'add' and 'sort' to it, along with other information that might be useful (like date modified). It's hard to know without understanding the full context of usage, but that's why it is hard to give a specific answer.
